# Jutification in Parallel Latex Environment

Tags: latex

The below code works, but two problems:

1. The justification is not working, so each column bleeds into the white space and is not fully justified.
2. I would like a vertical line separating the two columns: on the right edge of the left column.
3. And the paragraphs don't seem to be indenting, or having space between them.

Ideas?

The \tolerance code normally works to solve the justification issues, but it is not here.  And, the \colseprulecolor{CustomGrey} normally works for a line, but is not here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,                                                        %  Choose paper size
                    left=   1.0in,                                                      %  Set the margins                              
                    right= 1.0in,                                                       %
                    top=   1.0in,                                                       %
                    bottom=1.5in]{geometry}                                 %

\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}                                                 % Needed for the column environment
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                 % Apostrophes and quotes need this
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                                           % Needed for header and footer lines and colors
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pythontex}                                                      % Allows for the inclusion of Python code
\usepackage{lastpage}                                                           % Needed for page numbering
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}                                         % Needed for the colors in the commands 
\usepackage[font={scriptsize}]{caption} 
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{parallel}


 %---------------------------- Colors ----------------------------------------------------------------------------% 

\definecolor{CustomOrange}{rgb}{1, 0.43529, 0.01176}            % Define custom colors
\definecolor{CustomGrey}{rgb}{0.4745, 0.4745, 0.4745}       % Define custom colors

%---------------------------- Header & Footer -------------------------------------------------------------------% 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.0pt}                                % Thickness of  header rule

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{CustomOrange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}    

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}                                  % Thickness of  header rule

\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{CustomOrange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}

\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}             % Page numbering

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                                                     % Indentation of paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0.35cm plus0mm minus0mm}                   % Used to set space between paragraphs. Requires {parskip}

\setlength\headheight{60pt} 


%---------------------------- Set Columns -----------------------------------------------------------------------%  

%\columnsep=0.05\textwidth                                                  % Set space between columns
%\setcolumnwidth{.35\textwidth, .6\textwidth}                           % One entry for each column, see paracol{} below 

\tolerance=1                                                                                % Code fixes the justification issue with columns flowing over
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen                                                 %
\hyphenpenalty=10000                                                            %
\hbadness=10000                                                                     %

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.0pt}                                           % Thickness and color of vertical line between columns
\colseprulecolor{CustomGrey}                                                %


%---------------------------- Begin Document---------------------------------------------------------------------%  

\begin{document}

  \begin{Parallel}{2in}{4in}

    \ParallelLText{\lipsum[1-7]}
    \ParallelRText{\lipsum[2-6]}

  \end{Parallel}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1** can be fixed using the `\sloppy` keyword. It is Used to take care of columns/boxes with small width to stop the bleeding.

**Problem 2** will eliminated when you change `\begin{Parallel}{2in}{4in}` to `\begin{Parallel}[v]{2in}{4in}`. The `[v]` denotes *vertical line between columns*.

**Problem 3** is occurring because of the `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` line that you specified in your preamble. This resets the indentation in the whole document.

**Putting everything together:**

```
%Remove the follwing line:     \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{Parallel}[v]{2in}{4in}
    \sloppy
    \ParallelLText{\lipsum[1-7]}
    \ParallelRText{\lipsum[2-6]}
\end{Parallel}
```

Now these should fix your problems.

**EDIT!**

Here is another solution using `paracol`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,                                    % Choose paper size
                    left=   1.0in,                          % Set the margins                              
                    right= 1.0in,
                    top=   1.0in,
                    bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 % Apostrophes and quotes need this
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                       % Needed for header and footer lines and colors
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pythontex}                                      % Allows for the inclusion of Python code
\usepackage{lastpage}                                       % Needed for page numbering
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}                             % Needed for the colors in the commands 
\usepackage[font={scriptsize}]{caption} 
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lipsum}                                         % Random text
%---------------------------- New Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{paracol}                                        % Used for creating independent columns as well as page layout
\usepackage{float}                                          % Allows to insert table/figure in the exact position by using the H parameter
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                                 % No hyphenation
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                        % Allows to wrap table/figure to span both left and right column

\definecolor{CustomOrange}{rgb}{1, 0.43529, 0.01176}        % Define custom colors
\definecolor{CustomGrey}{rgb}{0.4745, 0.4745, 0.4745}       % Define custom colors

%---------------------------- Header & Footer -------------------------------------------------------------------% 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.0pt}                        % Thickness of header rule

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{CustomOrange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}    

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}                          % Thickness of footer rule

\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{CustomOrange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}

\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}         % Page numbering

\setlength\headheight{60pt}

%---------------------------- Paragraph Style -------------------------------------------------------------------%
\setlength\parindent{0pt}% no indentation
% The two lines below used to set the space between paragraphs to 0.35cm
\setlength\parskip{0.35cm}
\setlength\parsep{\parskip}

%---------------------------- Set Columns -----------------------------------------------------------------------%
\setcolumnwidth{0.35\textwidth,0.65\textwidth}              % Size of columns (col 1 and col 2) respectively
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.0pt}                           % Thickness and color of vertical line between columns
\colseprulecolor{CustomGrey}                                % Color of the vertical line between columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}                                 % Size of the space between columns.

%---------------------------- Color of Document -----------------------------------------------------------------%
\backgroundcolor{c[0]}[RGB]{255, 186, 186}                  % Color of left column (light red)
\backgroundcolor{c[1]}[RGB]{186, 186, 255}                  % Color of right column (light blue)
\backgroundcolor{g}{yellow}                                 % Color of space between the columns
\backgroundcolor{t}{green}                                  % Color of top margin
\backgroundcolor{b}{purple}                                 % Color of bottom margin
\backgroundcolor{l}{brown}                                  % Color of left margin
\backgroundcolor{r}{orange}                                 % Color of right margin
\backgroundcolor{p}{black}                                  % Color of the space remaining when the columns don't span the whole page (IMPORTANT!)

%---------------------------- Miscellaneous --------------------------------------------------------------------%

% Paracol uses its own numbering of tables/figures, \globalcounter* allows to
% Use the default numbering that latex uses. It is needed because it will mess
% the numbering in your document.
\globalcounter*
% \printpythontex                                           % You might need this??
%---------------------------- Begin Document---------------------------------------------------------------------%  
\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        % We start at left column (column[0])
        \sloppy
        \textbf{Beginning of paragraph 1 (placed on the left column).} \lipsum[1] \textbf{End of paragraph 1.}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{First figure in document and is placed in the first column (first figure in column 1).}
        \end{figure}
        % End of left column
        \switchcolumn[1]
        % Start at the right column (column[1])
        \textbf{Beginning of paragraph 2 (placed on the right column).} \lipsum[2] \textbf{End of paragraph 2.}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Second figure in document and is placed in the second column (first figure in column 2).}
        \end{figure}
        % End of right column
        \switchcolumn[0]
        % Switch back to left column (column[0])
        \textbf{Beginning of paragraph 3 (placed on the left column).} \lipsum[3] \textbf{End of paragraph 3.}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{Third figure in document and is placed in the first column (second figure in column 1).}
        \end{figure}
        % End of left column
        \switchcolumn[1]
        % Switch to right column (column[1])
        \textbf{Beginning of paragraph 4 (placed on the right column).} \lipsum[4] \textbf{End of paragraph 4.}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Fourth figure in document and is placed in the second column (second figure in column 2).}
        \end{figure}
        \textbf{Beginning of paragraph 5 (placed on the right column).} \lipsum[5] \textbf{End of paragraph 5.}
        \begin{table}[H]% Try here, and then top
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
                \hline
                cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
                cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
                cell1 & cell2 & cell3 & cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{The one and only table in the document. It is placed in column 2.}
        \end{table}
        % End of right column   
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Curious, \setlength{\parskip}{0.35cm plus0mm minus0mm} does not seem to work to put space between paragraphs (I had this in conjunction with \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} so I would have no indent, but space between paragraphs).

Comment: It seems that it is not supported via the parallel package (oh that package is very old by the way (last update is in 2003) and very very limited). If you want, tell me all the necessary requirements (ALL of them) that you would like to have and I will have to come up with a solution from scratch.

Comment: Thank You!  I want: 1) two columns that I can independently size in terms of width, 2) I want the text to be independent in each column, meaning it does not flow from one to the other column, 3) I want to insert graphics and text in the left hand column (I played with paracol quite a bit, but I can't seem to get the graphics to place properly next to the text in the right hand column - using \switchcolumn*) and 4) ideally I would like to choose the color of the background of the column and the color of the vertical line separating the columns.  Also, I am using pythontex for the graphics, etc.

Comment: For #3, you want to place an image/figure in the left column (and left column is independent for the right one) but you want it to match the text belonging in the right column? So they are independent columns but when it comes to images/figures, you want them to (in a sense) merge together? then, after the figure is place, they are independent again?

Comment: Basically, I want to precisely control where the images in the left hand column go.  I may want it next to the third paragraph in the right hand column.  So in paracol, which I played with, I would put the two columns of text in the right column, then issue a \switchcolumn* command and it would place text in the left hand column starting horizontal with para 3 in the right column.  But as soon as I start inserting graphics, everything gets jumbled in the left hand column - it becomes unperedicable.